# Teflon (PTFE) against another teflon

Tags: friction, material-science

Would teflon sleeve spinning againts teflon bushing create so much friction that it would just break?
I have a teflon bushing spinning againts metal sleeve, and it is the original design, which works.
I was wondering if teflon againts teflon would work as well.